# Unable to Port Bundles in Web8

Tags: web8.5, bundles, content-porter

We've been using Bundles for a few months now but one thing that's really restricting what we can do with them is the Porting of them and I can't figure out how to do this.

We have the usual hierarchy of publications: [01 Functionality], [02 Design] & [02 Content] and [05 Website].  Our content editors have been creating Bundles in [05] and adding various content components from the blueprinted folders and pages from the structure groups to them. They are then able to publish the Bundle to publish all the necessary items at once - this appears to work ok.  What would be even more useful is being able to port the Bundle between our Web8 environments, but we have been unsuccessful in doing so.  The error we get is:

> Item /webdav/...[full path]... cannot be imported because it is absent on import TCM and its content was not exported to the package.

I was hoping that just selecting the Bundle for export would export not just the Bundle but all its contents too.  I've made sure "Export shared items from owning publication" is selected and all the dependency checkboxes are selected but the error still occurs.

I've tried creating separate Bundles for each publication, eg. one for Content stored in [02 Content], one for design components stored in [02 Design] and one for pages stored in [05 Website], I then selected each Bundle for export but still no luck on import.  I've tried then adding the [02] Bundles to the [05] Bundle, selecting that for export and then importing but the error persists.

I believe the export is running correctly as the log shows the items exported coming from all the different publications and on inspection of the generated zip file, all the necessary components are in there in the correct folders with both the owning and blueprinted publication IDs.

Short of selecting each and every component in the Bundle in its original location within each of the publications, which defeats the object of using the Bundle for porting, what am I missing?  I'm sure it must be possible, I've seen a few posts on here/forums where it says things like "...and port the Bundle..."

Other info:

- We create Bundles without a Schema (does it need one?  If so, what?).
- We don't use workflow.
- We are using Web8.5 and Web8 Content Porter.

Full export Log:

```
Export finished successfully.
Start time: 1/5/2018 10:47:21 AM
End time: 1/5/2018 10:48:05 AM
Items exported: 109
Items failed: 0
Exported items:
/webdav//Bitmap%20image.tmt
/webdav//Cascading%20style%20sheets.tmt
/webdav//Excel%20sheet.tmt
/webdav//Executable.tmt
/webdav//Flash%20file.tmt
/webdav//Flash%20video.tmt
/webdav//Gif%20image.tmt
/webdav//jar%20%28ContentPorter-generated%29.tmt
/webdav//Java%20script.tmt
/webdav//Jpeg%20image.tmt
/webdav//Mp3%20music.tmt
/webdav//Mpeg%20video.tmt
/webdav//MSAccess%20database.tmt
/webdav//Pdf%20document.tmt
/webdav//Plain%20text.tmt
/webdav//Png%20image.tmt
/webdav//Powerpoint%20presentation.tmt
/webdav//QuickTime%20movie.tmt
/webdav//Real%20player.tmt
/webdav//Rich%20text.tmt
/webdav//Sound%20file.tmt
/webdav//Test1%20Publisher.tgp
/webdav//Test2%20Publisher.tgp
/webdav//WMV%20Video.tmt
/webdav//Word%20document.tmt
/webdav//XSL%20Document.tmt
/webdav//ZIP%20file.tmt
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D//Task%20Process.tpd
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D/Building%20Blocks
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Component%20Template.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Multimedia%20Schema.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Page%20Template.tpts
/webdav/sanitised5B00%20Master%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D//Task%20Process.tpd
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Component%20Template.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Multimedia%20Schema.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Page%20Template.tpts
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Content.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Metadata%20Schemas
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Metadata%20Schemas/CT%20metadata.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Metadata%20Schemas/Page%20metadata.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Multimedia%20Schemas
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Multimedia%20Schemas/Multimedia%20Schema.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/CT%20Keywords
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/CT%20Keywords/main-content-left.tkw
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/CT%20Keywords/main-content-right.tkw
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Global%20Nav%20Keywords
/webdav/sanitised5B01%20Functionality%5D/Global%20Nav%20Keywords/default.tkw
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D//Task%20Process.tpd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Bundles%20%5B02%20Content%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Bundles%20%5B02%20Content%5D/Test%20for%20porting
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Public
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Public/Test%20for%20Bundles%2001.xml
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Public/Test%20for%20Bundles%2002.xml
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Component%20Template.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Multimedia%20Schema.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Page%20Template.tpts
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Content.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Content%5D/Global%20Nav%20Keywords/default.tkw
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D//Task%20Process.tpd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Component%20Template.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Multimedia%20Schema.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Page%20Template.tpts
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Bundles%20%5B02%20Design%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Bundles%20%5B02%20Design%5D/Test%20for%20porting
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Component%20Templates
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Component%20Templates/Public
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Component%20Templates/Public/Content%20-%20Left%20Column%20--%20%5BCT%5D.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Component%20Templates/Public/Content%20-%20Right%20Column%20--%20%5BCT%5D.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Content.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Metadata%20Schemas/CT%20metadata.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/CT%20Keywords/main-content-left.tkw
/webdav/sanitised5B02%20Design%5D/CT%20Keywords/main-content-right.tkw
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D//Task%20Process.tpd
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Bundles%20%5B05%20Website%5D
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Bundles%20%5B05%20Website%5D/Test%20for%20porting
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Bundles%20%5B02%20Content%5D/Test%20for%20porting
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Public/Test%20for%20Bundles%2001.xml
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Content/Public/Test%20for%20Bundles%2002.xml
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Component%20Template.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Multimedia%20Schema.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Page%20Template.tpts
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Bundles%20%5B02%20Design%5D/Test%20for%20porting
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Component%20Templates/Public/Content%20-%20Left%20Column%20--%20%5BCT%5D.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Component%20Templates/Public/Content%20-%20Right%20Column%20--%20%5BCT%5D.tcts
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Building%20Blocks/System/Functionality/Schemas/Public/Metadata%20Schemas/Page%20metadata.xsd
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/sanitised%20Test%20Business%20Process
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Root
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Root/sanitised
/webdav/sanitised5B05%20Website%5D/Root/sanitised/Test%20for%20Bundles.tpg
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are exporting, it's likely you're not exporting dependencies. And there is a dependency that is required (which may be the item referred to above - or could be something deeper in the list) -  you'd need to sanitise/share the full log).

You could try with a single component (with a single simple text field - no links, keywords etc.) in the root content folder - this will confirm Content Porter itself is working (assuming the root folder name is the same and the schema exists and has the same WebDav URL).

Comment: I'm testing using a couple of existing CTs, two new test content components (which are as basic as possible - some dummy text in our most basic content schema) and a single page (using default PT and no metadata schema) using those CTs/Components.

When you say I'm 'likely not exporting dependencies', is that a specific option or are you asking if the dependant items are being exported?  If it's the former, I'm not sure where that option is, and if it's the latter then I know all dependency checkboxes are selected and the dependent content is in the exported file. See above for log.

Comment: Can you update the reference to "Item /webdav/...[full path]." ... is this [full path] something that matches your export log?

Comment: also worth considering is breaking your import into specific parts; try schemas, then templates, then content etc. often part of our standard "quick checks"

Comment: [deleted because I was replying to the wrong question]

Comment: The items listed in the error message do appear in the export log.

We've used the piece-meal approach to importing when we've had schemas refuse to import before, so I'll try that for this too.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify a bit the response Mark has gave you. He is completely right.

**Basically, when you export bundle, you don't export single item. You export virtual folder with references to items.** What it means? Basically, you say to Tridion: Export everything in this group, so each item is treated differently, and each item has its own dependencies.

So, the problem you have is following:

- dependency you need is not in package or,
- dependency you need is not
  present in target environment.

So you can fix this issue twofold. First way is to move dependencies separately, and then export main items without dependencies included in export package.

Or option 2 is to export everything together.

But I must warn you, Content Porter is tool you must know how to use, it won't read your mind. It exports only item you say it should export, so you must explicitly analyze exported items, and check if something is missing, therefore adding it to the package.